# What are the Specs of an iPad 3? How To Test For Retina?

Tags: ios, image, ipad, retina-display

So here's the issue:

I have a 3rd-generation iPad [(model number A1403)](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5452). On the linked Apple site, there is no evidence that the 3rd-generation iPad has a retina screen.

However, when I run my SpriteKit-based game, my @2x images are displayed. Therefore, I believe that the iPad 3rd-generation has a retina screen. Is that correct? (And Apple's site just omit's that info?) Is there a better way to check for retina?

Comment: And yes, the iPad 3 is retina.

Comment: Should I close this question then? I think it could be marginally helpful for those that look at the Apple documentation and are mislead (like myself).